# PUPPET Invalid byte Sequence in UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8, puppet

I've got a big problem with my puppet infrastructure.
I have a file which i want to copy to an other node.
This File is coded in us-ascii.
IMPORTANT: I am not allowed to change something of this file.

Do someone have the same problem or an solution?

My puppet class:

```
    class addfile::copy{
      file {'/tmp/FILE.def':
        ensure => file,
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => '0755',
        source => 'puppet:///modules/addfile/FILE.def',
      }
      notify {'File COPY':}
    }
```

My FILE.def contains all characters and all special characters.

My error message:

```
 Error: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
 Error: /Stage[main]/Addfile::Copy/File[/tmp/FILE.def]/content: change from {md5}XXIDXXX to {md5}XXIDXXX failed: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with Puppet. Apparently it is something to do with the way diffs are displayed during puppet apply when the show_diff option is on.

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1441

The ticket implies the problem is fixed in recent versions.

As a workaround, try running puppet agent with --no-show_diff:

```
 puppet agent -t --no-show_diff
```

Comment: Thanks, i already solve the problem by seting the "show_diff" to "no" in my module :-)